# Cartesian cubical interval with reversal?

Tags: cubical-type-theory

Background: cartesian cubical type theory (supports `i = j` as restriction, where `i` and `j` are interval vars). In this case, we gain the ability to express the "midpoint" of an interval as `i = ¬ i` (`¬ i` is defined as `1 - i`, so `1 - i = i` solves to `i = 0.5`). Does this idea make sense? Can we do anything interesting with the midpoints? The default cartesian cubical type theory does not have reversals, so they did not talk about this case.

Well, this is not my question, but a prelude. My real question is: given the following "x-cross" in a square (where `u` and `v` are terms):

- `i = j ⊢ u`
- `i = ¬ j ⊢ v`

[image]

My question: do we need to make sure that `i = j, i = ¬ j ⊢ u ≡ v` for the square construction to make (semantic) sense? The `≡` here is the judgment for def. equality. I can guess some possibilities:

0. They always hold.
1. They can be violated but that's okay.
2. They can be syntactically violated, but we have to rule out those cases for it to make semantic sense.

Comment: Can you clarify what u and v are here? Some sort of cofibration? An dimension variable? A term?

Comment: They're terms. I'll clarify

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is, but a while back Christian Sattler gave a presentation about many cubical models of type theory being anti-classical (LEM fails), and in the case of cubes with reversals, some construction involving the 'midpoint' was a key factor. This doesn't necessarily mean much for cubical type theories, because (I think) you can't carry out the construction within the type theory. But perhaps if you could talk about the midpoint things would be different. I've never seen a detailed explanation of the counterexample, though, so it's hard to say.